# Laravel 5.8 Auth::guard()->check() always return false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I use Auth:: guard Authentication.
I entered the correct email and password but it still returns false !!
But `Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($dataLogin)` returns `true`. I can't find a solution.
here is the login controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class adminController extends Controller
{
     use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

     const ALL_GUARD = ['admin'];

    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    function login(Request $request) 
    {
      $dataLogin = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
        foreach (self::ALL_GUARD as $guard) {
            dd(Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($dataLogin));
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($dataLogin)) {
                return redirect('/'.$guard.'/');
            }
        }
      return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'error!');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

}
```

here is the guest middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Traits\ResponseTrait;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class adminLogin
{
    const GUARD_ADMIN = 'admin';
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    use ResponseTrait;

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guard(self::GUARD_ADMIN)->check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return abort(401);
    }
}
```

Kerenel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\adminLogin::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

What did I do wrong? help me, thanks!

Comment: please add your error response and your route declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Go to “App/Http” and open Kernel.php file

Add this line

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

into the $middleware array.

```
 protected $middleware = [
     // add it here , first one
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Login attempt try  `Auth::attempt($credentials)`
instead of the
`Auth::guard()->attempt()`

Check this out from laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Auth::guard()->attempt($dataLogin);
```

or this

```
 Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($dataLogin)`
```

1. If you wish to use newly created `admin` guard throughout the application, you can change the value in **defaults** of config file.

---

2. If it is only about **AuthController** that uses Laravel's in built Auth system, you can add this line in the *AuthController.php* and *PasswordController.php* :

```
    protected $guard = 'admin';
```

Ref - Check **Guard Customization** [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

---

3. If you wish to you a guard other than default one for any Auth related task, you can specify it manually like this :

```
    // For route middleware
    Route::get('something', [
        'middleware' => 'auth:admin',
        'uses' => 'somethigController@show'
    ]);

    // For manually logging the user in
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authenticated...
    }
    
    // To login specific user using eloquent model
    Auth::guard('admin')->login($user);

    // For getting logged in user
    Auth::guard('admin')->user();
    
    // To check if user is logged in
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        // Logged in
    }
```

Ref - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication